# Insert data to DB very frequently in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

Is there any way to save/insert data to database vert frequently ? I have a list which contains 100 details of student records like name, age, class etc. Actually these data are getting from another website and i want to save these records to sql server 2012. SQLBulkCopy is not suitable for this issue.

I am using db query like shown below :

```
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBHelper.DBConnection))
             {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {                     
                    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tableA.....";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                conn.Close();
             }
```

Currently i am doing like - i take first student record from the list [foreach(Student stud in list)] and use the above query to save each student.

If we use the sql connection open and closing frequently , will it be end up with any problem ???

Is there anyway that we can save the data to database very frequently ??

please help.

Comment: `i take first student record from the list...` If you have a list of items you could insert all of them in a loop with one connection object.  Otherwise you haven't described what the problem is.  That insert statement with no Parameters is very troubling though.

Comment: *Is there anyway that we can save the data to database very frequently ??* - er. Yes. Now would you like to ask a better, more focused question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have them in a list, you could insert all of them in a loop without closing the connection. Opening and closing connections to the database won't cause any problems though, as long as the closed connections are properly disposed of after you're done with them. That said, you could investigate parallelism for your project by using Parallel.ForEach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netcore-3.1. A reference to System.Threading.Tasks is required to use it.

EDIT: Some example code on how you might use Parallel.ForEach:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace WindowsFormsApp12
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // define the concurrent collection we'll use to leverage parallelism
        private ConcurrentBag<Student> allStudents = new ConcurrentBag<Student>();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(Student s in GetStudents())
            {
                // populate the concurrent collection with the student object
                // depending on how your code works, you may be able to modify the method that gets the data
                // from the web services to return this kind of collection and avoid this step
                allStudents.Add(s);
            }
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    // MaxDegreeOfParallelism can be adjusted to suit your needs. We address the current Student
                    // object on the thread with the object s
                    Parallel.ForEach(allStudents, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, (s) =>
                     {
                         using (SqlConnection con = GetConnection())
                         {
                             using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                             {
                                 cmd.Connection = con;
                                 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblStudents ...";
                                 con.Open();
                                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                 con.Close();
                             }
                         }
                     });
                    // you may want to clear the allStudents collection here if your code runs through this
                    // operation several times in a day
                }).Wait();
            }).Start();

        }

        private SqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            // return a SqlConnection object wiht an appropriate connection string
            return new SqlConnection();
        }

        private List<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            // do something to populate the list
            return new List<Student>();
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        // class definition for the student object type
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Class { get; set; }
    }
}
```